# How do I get the orignal name of the file that is uploaded in the filefield in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to access the name of the file uploaded to `models.FileField()` in my class.

Here is my class

```
class extract(models.Model):
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
```

Is there a function or some method, to access the original name of the uploaded file, without modifying the name during upload.

like something like this

```
name = doc.filename()
```

Edit - 2:

I'm very new to django and programming in general. So this might seem stupid but I want something like this:

```
class extract(models.Model):
    def get_name(instance,filename):
        path = 'files'
        name = filename      
        return name,path
    
    doc = models.FileField(fname,upload_to==get_name)
    
    def ex(fname):
        path0 = "E:/Projects/PDF Converter/pdf/files/"
        fullpath = path0 + fname
        document = open(fullpath)
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(document)
        page1 = reader.getPage(0)
        data = page1.extractText()
        return data
    
    text = models.TextField(default=ex(fname),editable=False)
```

Comment: That's not how you use `default=` at all. Also, you have a typo in your `upload_to`...

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), this can be accomplished by passing a callback function as the `upload_to` argument, and the callback function will be called with the given filename as the second argument:

```
def get_filename(_, filename):
    print(filename) # or do whatever you want with the original filename here
    return 'files/'

class extract(models.Model):
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to=get_filename)
```

Comment: I have edited my question can you please try and help me with that

Comment: Not sure what you want with your newly posted code. If you want the text field to be prepopulated with the filename then it is impossible since the default argument is set when the class is defined, not when the user uploads a file.

Comment: Okay what I want is a variable that holds the name of the uploaded file for every object of the class extract